# asp.net + exceptions and redirecting

Tags: asp.net, exception

My intention is to log an error(I am using Log4Net) when an exception is caught and redirect to a pretty looking page with some error message. I have a class that returns a Type T object , mostly a DataSet.

In my Catch statement I wrote this, it works but I am not sure if there's a more appropriate way of handling, can someone please advice. Thanks. Note that the throw cannot be omitted because the class has a return type.:

```
      catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/errorPage.aspx");
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: Are you having to put this code in all places you want to log? If so, perhaps it would be better in the Global.asax in the `Application_Error` block; you will only need it once then. Note, you may need to check `ex.InnerException` to get the actual exception though. And use `Server.Transfer` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, if I place the error handling in my Global.ascx, the errors that occurs in page level becomes unhandled exception and stops my program. It ultimately still goes to my errorPage though. How do I prevent the program from stopping. Thanks?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the code in the global you will see that it gets hit. That's it's point; to catch all the unhandled exceptions. Your seeing it stop your program because you're in debug mode.

Comment: Just a note.. you don't need the try-catch block in the global..

Comment: Thanks for all that info, really helpful!

Comment: As mentioned in above replies, place common error handling in global events and if you wish to show error messages on the same page, then follow your approach i.e, logging the exception in catch block and return error message to SAME page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon how you want to handle error on the page, In general , unhandled  exception should be bubbled up to application_error in gloabl.asax file to it generic.Here is one simple way to handle this error.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
// Get the exception object.
Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

// Handle HTTP errors
if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
{
// The Complete Error Handling Example generates
// some errors using URLs with "NoCatch" in them;
// ignore these here to simulate what would happen
// if a global.asax handler were not implemented.
  if (exc.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || exc.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
  return;

//Redirect HTTP errors to HttpError page
  Server.Transfer("HttpErrorPage.aspx");
}

  // For other kinds of errors give the user some information
 // but stay on the default page
  Response.Write("<h2>Global Page Error</h2>\n");
 Response.Write(
  "<p>" + exc.Message + "</p>\n");
  Response.Write("Return to the <a href='Default.aspx'>" +
  "Default Page</a>\n");

 // Log the exception and notify system operators
 ExceptionUtility.LogException(exc, "DefaultPage");
 ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(exc);

 // Clear the error from the server
 Server.ClearError();
}
```