# Prevent redirect on web form error

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, webforms, submit

I'm working on a site written in asp.net, I have a form bounded to a sqldatasource. Happens that when errors occur during form submission, the user is redirected to the error page. What I want to obtain is to show the error on the same page, or in an alert, remaining in the same page.

I do not need to know how to show an alert or how to append code to a page, I just want to find a way to stop the page from redirecting.

I need something like "preventDefault ()" in javascript, to have something like:

```
Protected Sub Page_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Error
        Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError()

        //Report exception to user
        ...

        //Then prevent someway page from redirect
        preventDefault() //Need something similar
        //or
        Return false     //Need something similar

    End Sub
```

NOTE I already knew try/catch method , I'm seeking a way to block the page in case of unhandled errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i saw that you had tried the `try-catch` statement.

So, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091437/asp-net-exceptions-and-redirecting) for a full explanation.

Comment: I already knew this , I'm seeking a way to block the page in case of unhandled errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `try ... catch` block to catch the error before it reaches ASP.NET error handling mechanism. You can choose what to do with the exception inside the `catch` block. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) has more information on the subject.

Comment: I already knew this , I'm seeking a way to block the page in case of unhandled errors

Comment: To catch uhandled errors catch the generic Exception from which all exception inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Server.ClearError()`

Comment: I already knew this , I'm seeking a way to block the page in case of unhandled error

Comment: Sorry. I see you added that note now.

Comment: I tried this method. clears the error but I get redirected in any case, in a completely empty page.

Comment: I understand what you say. But note that URL still remains same - Page doesn't get redirected, though response is getting cleared from the page.

Comment: If you are just concerned about remaining on the same page; then using Respone.Redirect("Default.aspx") (Assuming you are on Default.aspx page) is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at these, if you want to use Jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Here's a nice bit of jQuery that I've used before

```
    $('#FORMID').submit(function ()
    {
        if(AN_ERROR)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

returning 'false' stops the default behaviour of the page redirecting.

Hope this helps.